# How to change button size to not take up the full frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jtextfield

I'm trying to make a simple GUI in Java in a `JFrame`, but whatever I try, it always looks like this:

[image]

How can I make it that the button doesn't take the whole window?

Here's my current code:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JTextField {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
        JButton button = new JButton("text");
        Dimension bttn = new Dimension(50, 50);
        button.setPreferredSize(bttn);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        textField = new JTextField(20);
        frame.add(textField);
        frame.pack();
        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html lots of good swing info :)

Comment: _**How can I make it that the button doesn't take the whole window?**_  what do you want to display in the empty space? Please add the layout you are trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[image]

The reason the text field does not appear at all is that (the content pane of) a `JFrame` has a `BorderLayout` by default. A component added to a border layout with no constraint is added to the `CENTER`, which can only accommodate a single component.

Make that single component a `JPanel` instead. A panel defaults to `FlowLayout` (which can display more than one component). Add the button and text field to the panel.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the button size with the below command.

```
button.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 80);
```

Comment: This won't work. By default Swing uses layout managers. The layout manager gives the button the size/location.

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score -1):

Here's a brief about setbounds

```
setBounds(int x-coordinate, int y-coordinate, int width, int height)
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-the-use-of-setbounds-method-in-java

you can also use `button.setSize(x,y); button.setLocation(x,y);`

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Thank you for filling me in too